# How can I maintain a global variable value in a chrome extension while a form changes within an iframe?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a form that has an iframe.  Within this iframe is a system of navigation between different views of the form like items, address, shipping info (these are < a > tags in a < li > tag).  As you navigate through the different views, the url of the page doesn't change, but the form view does.  I would like to capture the value of the item codes on the items tab from within a chrome extension and use these values to show/hide information on the shipping info view.  The only file I have on the chrome extension is a content.js file

I can capture the item codes and print to the console.  I thought I could hold the list of item codes in a global variable so that when I reached the shipping info, I could check for a specific code.  I also tried setting a true/false variable if a certain code was entered. Unfortunately, once you leave the items view, the variable is reset.

The below does not work:

```
Var myglobablvariable = “foo”;

Window.onload = function(){
                Console.log(‘before:  ‘ + myglobablvariable); // prints “before:  foo”
                Somefunction(); // called with an on blur event listener
                Console.log(‘after:  ‘ + myglobablvariable); // prints “after:  no foo”
};

Somefunction (){
                Myglobablvariable = “no foo”;
};
```

How can I save the 'no foo' as a type of global variable so it will be accessible when the user moves from the items to the shipping info view?  Thank you!

Comment: Use chrome.storage.local.

Comment: @wOxxOm That works!  If you will post as an answer, I will mark it as accepted with many thanks!